# arrange odd-even number in c

Tags: c

Write a program that inputs an array of n integers 5<=n<=50
Arrange odd numbers in even positions in ascending order writing c code

Example 1: input: 6 2 7 2 1 2 5 // 6 is the number of array elements followed by the elements

OUTPUT:

2 1 2 5 2 7

Example 2: input 8 2 9 21 3 4 7 23 6

OUTPUT:

2 3 21 7 4 9 23 6

Comment: `c`? `javascript`? please select one and add your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Examples of positions for sorting

```
  v   v   v
2 7 2 1 2 5          indices: [1, 3, 5]    values: [7, 1, 5]
2 1 2 5 2 7     

  v    v   v
2 9 21 3 4 7 23 6    indices: [1, 3, 5]    values: [9, 3, 7]
2 3 21 7 4 9 23 6
```

You could get the (even) indices **and** (odd) values, store the indices and values in arrays, sort the array of values and assign values to previously stored indices.